# Implementing List class with using Stack class

Tags: c++, c++11, language-design

I'm trying to write a Interpreted programming language like Python, so i need a List class for storing 'address of' functions and variables. I'm implemented Stack class for implementing List class:

```
typedef unsigned int UIntegerP; //This type for storing addresses
#define Free 0x0

template <typename T> class Stack{ 
    public:
        unsigned long UsedBSize; // You can use that like End Of Stack (EOS)

        Stack(void){
            this->BSize = 0; this->UsedBSize = 0;
            this->Buffer = new T;           
        }
        ~Stack(void){
            delete this->Buffer;
        }

        inline void Push(T Variable){ 
            if(this->UsedBSize == this->BSize){ 
                this->BSize++; 
            } this->Buffer[this->UsedBSize] = Variable; this->UsedBSize++;
        }    
        inline T Pop(bool IsProtected = false){ 
            if(IsProtected){
                return this->Buffer[this->UsedBSize]; 
            }else{
                this->UsedBSize--; T Element = this->Buffer[this->UsedBSize]; this->Buffer[this->UsedBSize] = Free; 
                return Element;
            }   
        }   
    private:
        T *Buffer;
        unsigned long BSize; 

};
```

And this is the class i want to implement:

```
class List{
    private:
        Stack<UIntegerP> *stack = new Stack<UIntegerP>; //A stack for storing variable addresses

    public:
        ~List(void){
            delete this->stack;
        }

        List(Stack<UIntegerP> Elements){ 
            while(Elements.UsedBSize != 0){
                this->stack->Push(Elements.Pop());
            }
        }

        List(Stack<UIntegerP> *Elements){
           while(Elements->UsedBSize != 0){
               this->stack->Push(Elements->Pop());
           }
        }

        UIntegerP Get(unsigned long Size); //Get Address with Index number
        UIntegerP Set(unsigned long Size, UIntegerP Address); //Set Address with Index number
};
```

I will use this List class for implementing Python like dictionaries. UIntegerP type is required for Variable class. How i can implement this two functions?

Comment: A list is a very simple data structure by itself, one of the basic and generic data structures. In fact it's common to built other data-structure (like a stack) from using a list. There are also other reasons that a stack is a bad choice for base of a list, for example a stack can't actually be iterated over. If you want a list, why not use the [standard library `std::list` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Because i'm trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Then at least try to do it properly. :) Create a node class, with `next` and `prev` pointers, and use that as the basis of the `List` class. Then in the `List` class have a pointer to the `head` and `tail` of the list of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your stack exposes only the `Push` and `Pop` functions, then you can't efficiently implement list with indexing on top of that.

If you're programming in normal C++ style, then the basic data structure would be a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) or a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). You can then build a stack on top of those. But note that indexing in a linked list is going to be slow (linear time complexity).

If you're programming in a functional style, then the basic structure is "list", which is an immutable singly-linked list and it's effectively the same as immutable stack. But again, indexing with that is going to be slow.

---

Also note that your `Stack` is implemented incorrectly: you're allocating memory for a single `T`, but then you assume you can use that for an unlimited number of `T`s. You either need to go the linked list route: allocate a new node for each item and connect the nodes with pointers; or you need to go the dynamic array route: allocate an array of a certain size and when it gets too small, reallocate it.

Comment: If i do not reallocate it, how it can be cause a problem?

Comment: @A.Ite You're accessing memory that you did not allocate. That means the memory could be owned by some other part of your process (causing very confusing and hard to debug behavior), or the memory could not be allocated from the OS at all, crashing your process.

Comment: It  will make the process hard as hell, i will need to write a code for enumerating the functions and variables, dictionaries, tuples, lists...

Comment: @A.Ite That's what you get when you decide to implement basic data structures from scratch. There is a reason why standard libraries exist. :-)